# How to write pattern for rename in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, gsub

I have several files of this type:

```
File-1 (vip)-eojUBB_8V_4.mp4
File-2 (vip)-Ek2iyeeL1Vc.mp4
File-3 (vip)-Gh8F6OJa0gU.mp4
File-4 (vip)-SvL_aZt3zyU.mp4
```

and wanna rename file to:

```
File-1.mp4 
File-2.mp4
```

Names "File1" and "File2" are just a example. Actually files have a different names but with "(vip)-smthing.mp4" in the end of filename.

I wrote the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'fileutils'
list = %x(ls -1 | grep .mp4).split(",")
list.each do |i|
  File.rename(i, i.gsub(/(vip)*.mp4/, ".mp4"))
end
```

but can't understand, what pattern I need to write inside gsub.

Bash example work's fine, but i need to write it on Ruby.

```
ls -1 | sed 's/-[^-]\+\././'
```

Comment: Try printing the before and after values before/instead of the rename.  Please update the question showing an example of the 2 prints.

Comment: With this example, I get the same name. This pattern doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'fileutils'
list = %x(ls -1 | grep .mp4).split(",")
list.each do |i|
  puts i.gsub(/ \(vip\)-\S+\./, ".")
end
```

Thanks to Philip Hallstrom and http://rubular.com/

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'fileutils'
list = Dir.glob('*.mp4')
list.each do |src|
  if src =~ /^(File\d+)/
    dst = "#{$1}.mp4"
    puts "renaming '#{src}' to '#{dst}'"
    File.rename(src, dst)
  end
end
```

Output:

```
$ ls
File1 (vip)-dHsq8aF2P0U.mp4 File2 (vip)-asdfsad.mp4     foo.rb

$ ruby foo.rb
renaming 'File1 (vip)-dHsq8aF2P0U.mp4' to 'File1.mp4'
renaming 'File2 (vip)-asdfsad.mp4' to 'File2.mp4'

$ ls
File1.mp4   File2.mp4   foo.rb
```

Comment: Are you sure your file names are what you think they are? I just ran the above and it's working (updating my comment now)

Comment: Yeah. Sorry. Names "File1", "File2" are just a example. Actually files have a different names but with "(vip)-smthing.mp4" in the end of filename. I need to create pattern for gsub - find "(vip)-smthing.mp4" and replace it with ".mp4". Thank you.

Comment: Oh, `if src =~ /^(.*?)\(vip\)/` .

Comment: Yeah, it works. 

`ruby rename.rb `
`renaming 'File2 (vip)-bFfq1pH480l.mp4' to 'File2 .mp4'`
`renaming 'File1 (vip)-dHsq8aF2P0U.mp4' to 'File1 .mp4'`

Good! But can u say me what i need to read for understand this?